# mvn compile assembly:single command in IntellijIdea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

What is the alternative of command {mvn compile assembly:single} when using intellijIdea? For me this command works in ubuntu bash but when I use intellijidea IDE then I can achieve the same goal by clicking the {clean} then {compile} then {install}.

Comment: You can [create](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-goals.html#run_goal) Maven run configuration in IDE with the same `compile assembly:single` maven goal.

Comment: Why do you call the goal of maven-assembly-plugin separately instead of using `mvn package`